# How to access multiple property files with single manager class in java

Tags: java, file, properties

I have around 10 property files for different purpose and I am creating a new class for each file to access the contents in it. I am thinking is there any possibility to create a class with a method like `.getValue(key,propertFileName)`.

So that if i call like `.getValue("name.type","sample.properties");`

Below is the code I am using to get value from the property file and I am using Core Java.

```
public class PropertiesCache {

    private final Properties configProp = new Properties();

    private PropertiesCache() {
        InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sample.properties");
        System.out.println("Read all properties from file");
        try {
            configProp.load(in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static class LazyHolder {
        private static final PropertiesCache INSTANCE = new PropertiesCache();
    }

    public static PropertiesCache getInstance() {
        return LazyHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    public String getProperty(String key) {
        return configProp.getProperty(key);
    }

    public Set<String> getAllPropertyNames() {
        return configProp.stringPropertyNames();
    }

    public boolean containsKey(String key) {
        return configProp.containsKey(key);
    }
}
```

With the below call I am able to get value from the sample.properties file.

```
PropertiesCache.getInstance().getProperty("name.type");
```

With the above code I am able to get content from a single property file. In order to get values from multiple files, I should create a separate Cache class for each file.

Can you please suggest me how to get property values from different property files with single manager class for them.

So `.getValue("name.type","sample.properties")` should return same value like `PropertiesCache.getInstance().getProperty("name.type")` did.

Answer (score 1):

Put your various property objects in a Map, which you populate with filenames as keys and the property bundles you read as values.

The "get" would be along the lines of:

```
Map<String, Properties> propsCache = .... // declare and fill elsewhere

public String getProperty(String name, String file) {
    Properties p = propsCache.get(file);
    return p.getProperty(name);
}
```

... add error handling as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Load all your properties files into a `Map`, and then use the filename as the key. For example:

```
public class PropertiesCache
{

    private Map<String, Properties> map = new HashMap<>();

    public PropertiesCache(List<String> filenames)
    {

        for (String f : filenames)
        {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            try
            {
                props.load(new FileReader(f));
                map.put(f, props);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                // handle error
            }
        }

    }

    public String getProperty(String file, String key) {

        Properties props = map.get(file);

        if (props != null) {
            return props.getProperty(key);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public Set<String> getAllPropertyNames()
    {

        Set<String> values = new HashSet<>();

        for (Properties p : map.values())
        {
            values.addAll(p.stringPropertyNames());
        }

        return values;

    }

    public boolean containsKey(String key)
    {
        for (Properties p : map.values())
        {
            if (map.containsKey(key))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

---

You might want to change the method signatures to accept the filename:

```
public Set<String> getAllPropertyNames(String file)
{

    Properties props = map.get(file);

    if (props != null)
    {
        return props.stringPropertyNames();
    }

    return null;

}

public boolean containsKey(String file, String key)
{
    Properties props = map.get(file);

    if (props != null)
    {
        return props.contains(key);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @starf. It worked for me. Only code modification required is, we need to initialize the map object. Everything worked great. Thanks again

Comment: @KrishnaD Great! I'll edit the answer with your changes. I should really have tested it...